# Epson V500 Photo + Kubuntu + iscan plugin package

Tags: drivers, epson

I'm trying to install Epson V500 Photo printer and I have followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195126)

I downloaded the drivers in right order but the last one "iscan plugin package" does not install to my computer. I use .deb files straight at the epson website so the installation is very easy, but this last one doesn't let me push the "install package" button.

Is there any other way to get the iscan plugin package?

I'm not so good with these things

Answer (score 0):

That maybe because some other Software Center widows are opened.

Place that deb file to your Home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-plugin*.deb
```

And you need to make sure that it is a package for your platform (i386 or amd64).

Comment: That doesn't work. It worke on my other computer just fine (fedora22) but in here kubuntu 14.04 this is not working.

Comment: @HekaTheAllMighty That does work. I use this scanner. Please give output of `dpkg -l | grep iscan` in your question. PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS.